# How to validate this IP address using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

i want to make regular expression to validate these type of ip addresses.like

```
       192.168.12.1       # it may be any proper ip address 

       193.168.34.3-3     # this format should also be acceptable
```

Because i want to take value from user in range.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which language/tool do you use?

Comment: Ruby on rails but i validate ubing this regex in js

Comment: no it is not typo i just trying to describer it can be any valid ip address

Comment: 255 is the maximum you can use in an ipv4 ... so if you have 344 somewhere, this is not a `valid ip address`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this regex.

```
/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}(?:\-([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))?$/
```

Answer (score 3):

```
^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.
([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$
```

is the regex for validating ip addresses in `0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255` format. What is the range for the last number, the one separated with `-`

**EDIT**

```
^([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.([01]?\d\d?)(?:\-([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5](?:\-([01]?\d\d?|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))?$
```

This should work for OP's scenario.

Comment: I think the OP wanted to have ranges i.e. `192.168.1.1-255` to be valid as well.

Comment: the edit one seems functional but it does not limit the ip e.g 192.168.1.1.1 it passess it otherwise its working

Answer (score 2):

The Rails way to validate with ActiveRecord in Rails 3 is:

```
@ip_regex = /^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/

validates :gateway, 
          :presence => true, 
          :uniqueness => true,
          :format => { :with => @ip_regex }
```

Answer (score 1):

`([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}[\-0-9]*)` will validate both your examples.. can you be more specific if you need it to match more?

Comment: all four should be {1,3}, and the * at the end should be ?.

Comment: why would I want a non-greedy operator at the end if `193.344.34.3-3` needs to match, the non-greedy will only match up to the `-` and not the entire IP address/range.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `([0-9] | [1-9][0-9] | 1[0-9][0-9] | 2[0-4][0-9] | 25[0-5])` "Pattern" for simplicity,
the RegEx would be;

```
Pattern\.Pattern\.Pattern\.Pattern(-Pattern)?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can start here

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/

and modify as you want.